# Correct syntax for using regex with variable in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.5.4

I have the below function where I am attempting to use the parameters within the Regex. Something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test(lastname text, firstname text, birthdate date)
  RETURNS SETOF view_patient AS
$BODY$ 

   select * from testing t
   where t.lastname ~*  '^' || $1 || ''
   order by t.lastname

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

The returned error is:

> ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text LINE 55:
>   where t.lastname ~*  '^' || $1 || ''

How is this done?

TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to put the concatenation between parentheses (and you can remove the empty string at the end:

```
where t.lastname ~*  ('^' || $1)
```

alternatively:

```
where t.lastname ~*  concat('^', $1)
```